# If X is normally distributed, and c is a constant, is cX also normally distributed?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

If $X\sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$, and if $c$ is a constant, is $cX$ also normally distributed? How do you show it?

If yes, does this apply to other distributions? So if $Y$ follows some type of distribution, will $cY$ also follow that distribution?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Usually written $X\sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ and so $cX\sim N(c\mu, c^2\sigma^2)$. Typically if Wikipedia describes a distribution as having a [scale parameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale_parameter) then you can multiply a random variable by a constant and have a distribution in the same family, though often it may have to be positive.

Comment: Yes, if $c\ne 0$ then $cX$ is normal.  For some distributions, scaling leaves you in the same family. For many others (binomial, for example) it doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to your first question is yes:  if $c \ne 0$ and $c \in \mathbb R$, then $cX \sim \operatorname{Normal}(c\mu, |c|\sigma)$ if $X$ is normal with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$.  This is because the normal distribution belongs to a location-scale family:  its PDF is $$f_X(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma} e^{-(x-\mu)^2/(2\sigma^2)}, \quad -\infty < x < \infty.$$  Then $Y = cX$ will have PDF $$f_Y(y) = \frac{1}{|c|} f_X(y/c),$$ and a little algebra will show that this is also a normal PDF.  I have left this second part as an exercise.

The answer to your third question, the answer is no: some distributions do not have a scale parameter.  Obvious examples are:  the binomial distribution and Poisson distribution.  These have discrete support on nonnegative integers.

There are continuous random variables that also do not have scale parameters:  one example is the Beta distribution $$X \sim \operatorname{Beta}(a,b), \quad a > 0, b > 0$$ has the PDF $$f_X(x) = \frac{\Gamma(a + b)}{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)} x^{a-1} (1-x)^{b-1}, \quad 0 < x < 1.$$  $cX$ is not itself Beta for obvious reasons similar to the discrete support examples:  the support is no longer $(0,1)$.

Comment: Heropup, your answer was more informative (and correct on the variance issue, that was a mistake on my part) so I removed my answer. Thanks for catching that!

Comment: Note here the second parameter is standard deviation instead of variance

Comment: @zsfly Yes, because in your original statement of the question, you parametrized $X$ by its mean and standard deviation rather than its mean and variance, and I went off of that.  Interestingly, the SD is the scale parameter for a normal distribution, so in a way, that is the more appropriate parametrization for your question.

Comment: Totally understand that !

Comment: Can we explain, please, why do we have the absolute value in  $\frac{a}{\lvert c \rvert}$ and not the minus sign inside pdf?