# Cumulative distribution function of $\sqrt{X^2+4Y^2}$ without $\chi$ distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I want to find the cumulative distribution function of the random variable $Z=\sqrt{X^2+4Y^2}$, where $X\sim N(0,4)$, $Y\sim N(0,1)$ are independent. I know it is equal to $\chi_{[0,\infty)}(t)\left(1-\exp\left(-\frac{t^2}{8}\right)\right)$, but I don't know how to show it.

My research has led me to the Chi-square distribution, however, this has never come up in class, and also the CDF for this distribution looks complicated enough on its own, without even taking the square root.

Noting that $$P(\sqrt{X^2+4Y^2}\le t) = 1-P(\sqrt{X^2+4Y^2} > t)$$
it would be sufficient to show
$$P(\sqrt{X^2+4Y^2} > t) = \exp\left(-\frac{t^2}{8}\right)$$
but I don't know how that could be done. How could I show this relation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables (a property that the OP has not admitted to as yet),
\begin{align}
F_{\sqrt{X^2+4Y^2}}(t) &= P(\sqrt{X^2+4Y^2}\leq t)\\
&= P\left(\sqrt{(X/2)^2+Y^2}\leq \frac t2\right) & \scriptstyle{\text{independent }}\frac X2, Y \sim N(0,1)\\
&= P\left(2 \text{ independent } N(0,1) \text{ RVs lie in disk of radius } \frac t2\right)\\
&= \iint_{\text{disc of radius }\frac t2} \frac{1}{2\pi}\exp\left(-\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}\right)\, \mathrm dx \,\mathrm dy\\
&=\int_0^{\frac t2}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{2\pi}\exp\left(-\frac{r^2}{2}\right)\, r\mathrm d\theta \,\mathrm dr\\
&= \int_0^{\frac t2} \exp\left(-\frac{r^2}{2}\right) r\,\mathrm dr\\
&= \left.-\exp\left(-\frac{r^2}{2}\right) \right\vert_0^{\frac t2}\\
&= 1 - \exp\left(-\frac{t^2}{8}\right)
\end{align}
without mentioning $\chi^2$ random variables etc at all.

Comment: Just one question: Isn't $X/2$ an $N(0,2)$ variable (not $N(0,1)$)? I'm referring to: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1543687/if-x-is-normally-distributed-and-c-is-a-constant-is-cx-also-normally-distribut

Comment: No, $\operatorname{var}(aX) = a^2\operatorname{var}(X)$ and so the variance of $X/2$ is one-fourth the variance of $X$. So, if by $N(0,4)$ you meant that $X$ has variance $4$, then $X/2 \sim N(0,1)$. If by $N(0,4)$ you meant that $X$ has _standard deviation_  $4$, then $X/2 \sim N(0,2)$. But then, your stated answer about what the CDF should work out to be is grossly incorrect and so I assume that the second parameter is the variance and not the standard deviation, if not according to you, at least according to whatever text you are using.

Answer (score 1):

As @dimebucker noted, we need to assume independence here. Let $W:=X/2$. The claim is equivalent to $R:=T/2=\sqrt{W^2+Y^2}$ having PDF $r\exp(-r^2/2)$ for $r\ge0$. This is easily proven with a switch to polar coordinates:$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\frac{-r^2}{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\frac{-y^2}{2}dwdy=r\exp\frac{-r^2}{2}dr\frac{d\theta}{2\pi}.$$Since this is separable in $R,\,\Theta$, the PDF of $R$ is $r\exp\frac{-r^2}{2}$ for $r\ge0$, as required.

Comment: Where did the $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp \frac{-w^2}{2}$... come from? Could you elaborate a bit please?

Comment: @RubenKruepper That is the PDF of the standard normal distribution.

Comment: @angryavian Yes, but he's squaring normal distributions!

Comment: @RubenKruepper J.G. is applying a change of variables to go from the joint density of $(W,Y)$ to the joint density of $(\sqrt{W^2+Y^2}, \arctan(Y/W))$ to obtain the density of $\sqrt{W^2+Y^2}$.

Comment: @angryavian [Technically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2), $\Theta=\operatorname{atan2}(Y, \, W)$.

Comment: @angryavian I've also never heard of atan2, I'm still sure there is a simpler solution.

Comment: @RubenKruepper You don't need to work out $\theta$ here. All we're using is $w^2+y^2=t^2,\,dwdy=tdtd\theta$.

Comment: I would be very grateful if you could clarify two things please, I feel there is a lot to learn here: 1. $T=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{X^2+4Y^2}$ and therefore doesn't match and 
2. How do you make the jump from the root of two squared and differently normally distributed variables to the product of the PDFs of two standard normally distributed variables? Thank you!

Comment: @RobertKrueppler See edit, where I now use $r$ as the name for half of your $t$.

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot to mention that $X$ and $Y$ are independent. Then note that $X = 2 Z$ where $Z \sim N(0,1)$, and so $X^2 = (2Z)^2 = 4 Z^2 \sim 4 \chi^2_1$, further, $4Y^2 \sim 4\chi^2_1$. We are therefore looking at the sum of two independent $4\chi^2_1$ random variables, which has distribution $4 \chi^2_2$. Then, $\sqrt{4 \chi^2_2} \sim \sqrt{2} \chi_2$, which is the distribution of the quantity of interest.

To show the result you had in the end we can use the above argument to note that
\begin{align*}
P(\sqrt{X^2 + 4Y^2} \le t) 
&=P( \chi^2_2 \le t^2/4)\\
&= \frac{1}{\Gamma(1)} \gamma(1, \frac{t^2}{8})\\
&= \int_0^{t^2/8} y^{1-1} e^{-y} dy\\
&= \int_0^{t^2/8} e^{-y} dy\\
&= 1-e^{-t^2/8}
\end{align*}
where $\gamma(a,b) = \int_0^a y^{a-1} e^{-y}$ is the lower incomplete gamma function, and I have used the fact that $P(\chi^2_k \le x) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(k/2)} \gamma(k/2, x/2$ (basically using the notation on the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-square_distribution) page)

Comment: OP seems to want to avoid using the chi-squared distribution since it hasn't been covered in their class (and probably is not allowed to simply cite the CDF of the chi-squared distribution from a reference).

Comment: I misunderstood as the OP said 'come up in my research' in which case they might be expected to go beyond what was taught in class and should take the time to learn about this alternative approach, hopefully it can help anyway